# How to get information on latest successful pod deployment in OpenShift 3.6

Tags: optimization, openshift, continuous-delivery, openshift-3

I am currently working on making a CICD script to deploy a complex environment into another environment. We have multiple technology involved and I currently want to optimize this script because it's taking too much time to fetch information on each environment.

In the OpenShift 3.6 section, I need to get the last successful deployment for each application for a specific project. I try to find a quick way to do so, but right now I only found this solution :

```
oc rollout history dc -n <Project_name>
```

This will give me the following output

```
deploymentconfigs "<Application_name>"
REVISION   STATUS    CAUSE
1          Complete  config change
2          Complete  config change
3          Failed    manual change
4          Running   config change

deploymentconfigs "<Application_name2>"
REVISION   STATUS    CAUSE
18         Complete  config change
19         Complete  config change
20         Complete  manual change
21         Failed    config change
....
```

I then take this output and parse each line to know which is the latest revision that have the status "Complete".

In the above example, I would get this list :

```
<Application_name> : 2
<Application_name2> : 20
```

Then for each application and each revision I do :

```
oc rollout history dc/<Application_name> -n <Project_name> --revision=<Latest_Revision>
```

In the above example the Latest_Revision for Application_name is 2 which is the latest complete revision not building and not failed.
This will give me the output with the information I need which is the version of the ear and the version of the configuration that was used in the creation of the image use for this successful deployment.

But since I have multiple application, this process can take up to 2 minutes per environment.

Would anybody have a better way of fetching the information I required?

Unless I am mistaken, it looks like there are no "one liner" with the possibility to get the information on the currently running and accessible application.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to ignore the running application for <Application_name>, and what info do you need exactly besides the config version?

Comment: The information I require is in some of the Environment info, also in the containers.
for instance we are needing the 
Image, CONFIGMAP_LONGVERSION & PROJECT_LONGVERSION

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the currently active deployment is the latest successful one, you may try the following:

```
 oc get dc -a --no-headers | awk '{print "oc rollout history dc "$1" --revision="$2}' | . /dev/stdin
```

It gets a list of deployments, feeds it to awk to extract the name `$1` and revision `$2`, then compiles your command to extract the details, finally sends it to standard input to execute. It may be frowned upon for not using xargs or the like, but I found it easier for debugging (just drop the last part and see the commands printed out).

**UPDATE:**
On second thoughts, you might actually like this one better:

```
oc get dc -a -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\n\t"}{.spec.template.spec.containers[0].env}{"\n\t"}{.spec.template.spec.containers[0].image}{"\n-------\n"}{end}'
```

The example output:

```
daily-checks
        [map[name:SQL_QUERIES_DIR value:daily-checks/]]
        docker-registry.default.svc:5000/ptrk-testing/daily-checks@sha256:b299434622b5f9e9958ae753b7211f1928318e57848e992bbf33a6e9ee0f6d94
-------
jboss-webserver31-tomcat

        registry.access.redhat.com/jboss-webserver-3/webserver31-tomcat7-openshift@sha256:b5fac47d43939b82ce1e7ef864a7c2ee79db7920df5764b631f2783c4b73f044
-------
jtask

        172.30.31.183:5000/ptrk-testing/app-txeq:build
-------
lifebicycle

        docker-registry.default.svc:5000/ptrk-testing/lifebicycle@sha256:a93cfaf9efd9b806b0d4d3f0c087b369a9963ea05404c2c7445cc01f07344a35
```

You get the idea, with expressions like `.spec.template.spec.containers[0].env` you can reach for specific variables, labels, etc. Unfortunately the `jsonpath` output is not available with `oc rollout history`.

**UPDATE 2**:
You could also use post-deployment hooks to collect the data, if you can set up a listener for the hooks. Hopefully the information you need is inherited by the PODs. More info here: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.10/dev_guide/deployments/deployment_strategies.html#lifecycle-hooks

Comment: `oc get dc -a` does not return the right information for example I have application_name that tell me revision 24. But revision 24 is actually a failed revision that gave an error. The active one is the revision 23.